# Does the Star Wars Squadron physical version have a disc or just a code?

Tags: star-wars-squadrons

Star Wars Squadrons was just released! Does the physical version have a disc that i can install the game from?  Some games just have boxes with codes in them, and I want to be able to install from the disc so i don't have to download all 30 gb of it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What details have been released on Star Wars Squadrons physical version?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/376255/what-details-have-been-released-on-star-wars-squadrons-physical-version)

Comment: It's best not to re-ask the same question. Instead you can ask to re-open the old one.

Comment: Since the last one was closed as unreleased, I strongly recommend against duplicating to that one.

Comment: I suggest that we allow this and simply answer the question if we know.  @Millard has been determined to try to find an answer, and I think the kindest thing to do would be to let him get an answer.

Comment: I've seen some physical releases where the disc either only contained a Steam installer (Skyrim) or the first 9 GB of 30 GB (Fallout 4), so just asking for whether there's a disk may not be enough.

Comment: thats a shame, as that's one of the main benefits of a disc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google search shows shops like GameStop are selling this game with the key word Disc, but closer inspection of the actual seller sight says it's digital suggesting just a code to download the game. Websites for BestBuy and Amazon only show digital download options. It seems like there probably will not be a disc released for this game, especially since it's mainly an online multiplayer game with a relatively small singleplayer section.

Comment: yeah, looks like they didn't make a physical version for the pc.  bummer.